# Strange JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a strange JS issue.

I've built a content management system. In the old version all worked well. Changed design a bit, implemented jquery ui theme, and upgraded jquery to the latest version. Now the change event for #menu select box doesn't work at all. Also there is no error on firebug. The screenshots below is taken from [Visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) results.

**The old version**. As you see there is change event for #menu select-box

[image]

And **new version**. The strange click event on the title appeared from nowhere. And there is no change event for #menu select box

[image]

HTML Markup Looks like that

```
...
          <select name="menu" id="menu">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
              <option value="1">sample 1</option>
              <option value="2">sample 2/option>
            </select>
...
```

The JS Side (pgsettings.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#parent").hide();
    $("#options").hide();
    $("input:submit").button();
    $('#menu').selectmenu();
    $("#options" ).buttonset();
    $("#menu").change(function () {
        var selectedmenu = $(this).val();
        if (selectedmenu != '' && selectedmenu != '0') {
            var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();

            $("#options").show();
            if (parentcheck === "1") {
                genOpts(selectedmenu);
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#options").hide();
            $("#parent").combobox("destroy");
            $("#parent").hide().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
            $(".parentcheck").removeAttr("checked").button("refresh");

        }
    });


    $(".parentcheck").change(function () {
        var selectedmenu = $("#menu").val();
        if ($(this).val() === "0") {
            $("#parent").combobox("destroy");
            $("#parent").hide().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');         
            $("#menu").change();
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            $("#parent").combobox("destroy");
            $("#menu").change();
        }
    });
});
```

I really can't find where I did wrong. Maybe I placed all jscript files at the end of the file? The whole html markup for [new version](http://pastie.org/2712859)  and [old version](http://pastie.org/2712867) If someone wants to take a look at my problem in action, I can give my teamviewer id. (I'm suggesting it because I have no url for the website to show the problem in action. I can share with you only local website)

Comment: Line 161 is `form>`, shouldn't it be `</form>`?  Probably not responsible for your issue, but worth fixing.  Improperly closed elements can cause extremely strange and difficult to diagnose `js` issues in some browsers.  Also, if you want to send me a link for the page in action I'm happy to take a closer look.

Comment: Do you have any IM? Skype or something?

Comment: I can show you only via Teamviewer. share with me your im so i can contact with you

Comment: @DanielMendel http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4336/strange-js-issue lets chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectmenu plugin is interfering with your original code. You will need to bind to the change event of the plugin itself, not the select. Look at the api for the selectmenu plugin for instructions on how to bind to its change event.

Edit: We discussed this in a chat room, the problem ended up being duplicate id's.

Comment: What to change exactly, my js is not very well. I'm stucked hard at this point

Comment: What selectmenu plugin are you using?

Comment: @DEVastator move the function from `$('#menu').change()` to `$('#menu').selectbox({ change: // change event here })`

Comment: It's for jquery ui theme implementation. I've tested without it too. No success

Comment: @Daniel i've tested it too, no success. Please give me any IM. I wanna talk to you if it's possible)

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't have a selectmenu widget. Where are you getting that widget from?

Comment: @KevinB There actually is a `selectmenu` widget in development for the official `jQuery UI`, it's just not included yet in the stable releases.  You can get to it here: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Comment: @DanielMendel True, however I wasn't going to assume that was the plugin he was using. If that is the plugin he is using, the change event you mentioned in the above comment should take care of it. What is making me skeptical is the fact that the change handler he is using is using the combobox plugin(which is an extended autocomplete).

Comment: @KevinB fair enough -- looks like there were other problems at work, a `.live()` call got through fine, so there must be some DOM work going on after the initial call.  They're sorting it out here right now: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4336/strange-js-issue

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a piece of advice.

You are not using local variables at all, and this ***will slow down your code***

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#parent").hide();
```

write

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parent = $("#parent");
    parent.hide();
```

so everywhere else in that block you are calling `$("#parent")` you can call `parent`

Think about it, each time you select #parent with jQuery you are running that selector engine magic, where if you stored it as a local variable you would only have to select the element once.

Comment: Well. but that's not solution. Can you take a look via teamviewer?